# Formato a salida de exec

Tags: c, exec

Estoy intentanto formar un prompt para un programa que  me incluya el nombre de usuario y directorio mediante una llamada exec.
Así hago la llamada a exec, esta salida la quisiera guardar en una variable aunque tengo entendido que exec me devuelve solo enteros. Pero cómo es posible darle formato para concatenar la salida con otros caracteres y otra salida de exec.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main(){
        int pid; 
        int status;
        char *arg[2]={"pwd",NULL};
        pid=fork();
        if(pid==-1){
            perror("Error en la llamada a fork\n"); 
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if(pid==0){
            execvp(arg[0], arg);
            perror("Error en exec");
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            pid=wait(&status);
            if(WIFEXITED(status))
                printf("Proceso hijo ejecutado");
            else
                printf("Proceso hijo no ejecutado");
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos, tienes la función [`popen( )`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

> #### FILE *popen( const char *command, const char *type );
>
> The `popen( )` function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell.
>   ...
>   reading from the stream reads the command's standard output.

Un ejemplo básico:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
  FILE *pwdFile = popen( "pwd", "r" );
  char buff[1024];

  fgets( buff, sizeof( buff ), pwdFile );

  pclose( pwdFile );

  printf( "%s", buff );

  return 0;
}
```

Observa como, a la hora de cerrar el `FILE` obtenido, es necesario llamar a [`pclose( )`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) en lugar de `fclose( )`.

Comment: Hay una manera posible que se imprima pero sin un salto de línea. Cuando me da la salida lo hace junto a un salto de línea y no puedo seguir dando formato e imprimir todo en una línea.

Comment: Si hay una manera, tienes que recorrer el array buff hasta que encuentre el salto de linea ('\n') una vez hallada la posicion del array que contiene ese caracter asignale el caracter fin de cadena ('\0')